# Exception unhandled occurring in Visual Studio windows form application. What could it be?

Tags: c#, sql

I am a university student studying Computing. For my programming assignment, I am required to make a C# Windows Form Application in Visual Studio to allow users to enter and store information in a database for Car Garage.

I have created a table and stored procedure for the customer details but when I test and run the system, I get an Exception Unhandled error message on the execute non query part of the code. This happens when I press the submit button on the form once all data has been entered.

Does anyone know why this is happening and could anyone push me in the right direction?

Thanks

(stored procedure for customer details)

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[AddDetails]
@CustomerName Varchar(50),
@CustomerAddress Varchar(50), 
@CustomerTelephone Varchar(50), 
@CustomerEmail Varchar(50), 
@CustomerType Varchar(15)

AS

Begin
Insert into [Customer]
([CustomerName]
,[CustomerAddress]
,[CustomerTelephone]
,[CustomerEmail]
,[CustomerType])
Values 
(@CustomerName
,@CustomerAddress
,@CustomerTelephone
,@CustomerEmail
,@CustomerType)
End
```

Table for customer details

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer] (
    [CustomerId]        INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerName]      VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerAddress]   VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerTelephone] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerEmail]     VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerType]      VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [Pk_Name] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CustomerId] ASC)
);
 ~ ~ ~
Code for the Add form 
 ~ ~ ~

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(txtName.Text =="" || txtAddress.Text =="" || txtPhoneNo.Text =="" || txtEmail.Text =="" || cboCustomerType.Text =="" 
                || txtMake.Text == "" || txtModel.Text =="" || txtRegistration.Text =="" || txtMaintenanceNo.Text =="" || cboService.Text ==""
                || txtDateofService.Text =="")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter all details");
            }
            else
            {
                using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    sqlCon.Open();
                    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("AddDetails", sqlCon);
                    sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    //add the data from the textbox into the @Name and store it in the database 
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerName", txtName.Text.Trim());
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerAddress", txtAddress.Text.Trim());
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerTelephone", txtPhoneNo.Text.Trim());
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerEmail", txtEmail.Text.Trim());
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerType", cboCustomerType.Text.Trim());
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarMake", txtMake.Text.Trim());
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarModel", txtModel.Text.Trim());
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarReg", txtRegistration.Text.Trim());
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaintenanceNo", txtMaintenanceNo.Text.Trim());
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Service", cboService.Text.Trim());
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Problems", txtProblems.Text.Trim());
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServiceHistory", txtServiceHistory.Text.Trim());
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateofService", txtDateofService.Text.Trim());





                    //execute query 
                    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //message box to show details have been entered 
                    MessageBox.Show("Details Saved");
```

Comment: What is the error message in the exception?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add 13 Parameters to the stored procedure call.
The stored procedure has only 5 Parameters defined.

This is why you get an exception, telling you that you are adding too many arguments.

You should only pass the parameters `AddDetail` needs, which are:

```
 @CustomerName
 @CustomerAdress
 @CustomerTelephone
 @CustomerEmail
 @CustomerType
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I am new to this so I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "pass the parameters that AddDetails needs", how do I do that? As I already have those parameters declared in the AddDetails procedure so i am not really sure

Comment: yes you have, and in addition to that, you pass 8 more arguments that are not defined in `AddDetail`

so you need to remove those 8 rows

so: 

remove or comment out all the lines starting from 

`sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarMake", cboCustomerType.Text.Trim());`


and ending with

`sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateofService", txtDateofService.Text.Trim());`

these lines try to push data into the stored procedure `AddDetail` which is not expecting that data. it only expects the above 5 arguments.

Comment: or, extend the stored procedure `AddDetail`, so that it accepts more data

Comment: Tried that but got the following error: "Procedure or function 'AddDetails' expects parameter '@CustomerType', which was not supplied.'"

Comment: yea you deleted one row too much, that one needs to be kept . (was my fault, original comment edited)

Comment: I have two other tables and procedures created for the car details and then the maintenance details

Comment: yes, but thats a different question :) 

there are many ways to solve that, one of them is that you call them in an extra call, (i.e. a new command, one per procedure) , other way would be that you redesign your 
stored procedurce... but as i said, thats a different question, the question about your exception has been solven